# Error: Could not symlink bin/dvipdf when installing Octave

Tags: octave, homebrew

I am trying to install Octave on Mac OS Mavericks with Brew. I ran

```
brew install octave --without-docs
```

which almost instantly gave me

```
Error: You must `brew link ghostscript' before octave can be installed
```

I did it, and it gave me the following:

```
Error: Could not symlink bin/dvipdf
Target /usr/local/bin/dvipdf
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm /usr/local/bin/dvipdf

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite ghostscript

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run ghostscript
```

I ran the last, which showed me a bunch of files I have never seen before. What shall I do? Erase them with brew link --overwrite ghostscript, or do something else?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same error message.  Did you install MacTeX before installing Octave?  I think it might be related.

Comment: I did, it seems to be indeed the one that owns these files..

Comment: Just FYI, I reposted my version of this error [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154056/error-could-not-symlink-bin-dvipdf-when-installing-octave).

Comment: So what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 3):

[This  work for me](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/1279)

1.you should delete `ghostscript` in `/usr/local/share`

2.`brew doctor`,it will prompt you with some options

3.brew link --overwrite ghostscript

4.you can `brew install octave`